# is there a way to disallow https connections to certain subdomains that do not have a certificated while using SNI

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, ssl-certificate, sni

At the moment I am using nginx as my webserver. Some time ago I found out about Server Name Indication (SNI), which was very helpful since I have a couple domains (including all the subdomains) running from my server.

So exited as I was, I put a ssl-certificate on my main domain and a couple of subdomains on my server. Works great, no problem :D

(the reason I didn't just use a wildcard-certificate is because I am using http://www.startssl.com/ which provides me with free ssl-certificates, but for wildcard I will have to pay, and my server isn't that important for that, it's merely a hobby-project)

So on to the question:
If someone browses to a non-existing (sub)domain, or one that does not have an certificate installed, they get of course a big warning in there browser, because nginx served the default certificate which of course does not match that non-existing domain.
I was wondering, would it be possible to tell nginx if the sni-system gets asked for a non-exisiting domain-name, to just terminate the connection or maybe do something so instead of a name-mismatch warning there will appear some other warning in the browser saying the site does not exist (if even such a system does exist...)

I know one solution: take away the wildcard-dns-record so non-existing will indeed not exist, but that doesn't help for the ones that exist, but not on https. Also with that I cannot easily just add a new subdomain and have to also edit dns-settings for it. (I know, I am lazy, but which nerd isn't :P)

Oh and if such thing is not possible I'll just have to live with the way it is now, not that big of a deal, but it would make my server less 'cooler' xd (im sorry, im just a random tech-hobbyist).

Comment: I would suggest asking this on ServerFault instead, but remove any mention of hobbyist, since it's meant for a professional context.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use SSL for subdomains :)
eg

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com;
    ...
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.example.com;
    ...
}
```

Comment: For every subdomain that didnt had a ssl-certificate there was already no `listen 443` in there. Turns out if you do go to a https-connection on such subdomain, nginx just serves the first ssl-(sub)domainname it can find. So while this wasnt exactly the solution, i did manage to get me thinking in the right way and find the solution! I'll add it as a answer myself

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer by SuddenHead was almost the solution. It needed just a tiny little additional step. I already had done what SuddenHead said, but if you would visit a non-existing subdomain, or a subdomain that doesnt have ssl it would just serve the first ssl-enabled subdomain it can find. The solution turns out to be very simple. Make sure you add a server-block to the nginx-config and make sure it is the ***first*** one nginx will read:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 default_server;

    return 404;
}
```

This will also serve a 404-page to any non-existing subdomain (something i also wanted, if not desired, I think omitting the `listen 80` rule should work) and because no ssl-certificate details are specified, accessing this on https gives an error about an ssl-connection that could not be established, instead of a domain-mismatch-error with warnings about something could be wrong and stuff. This is basically exactly what I was looking for :D

Now I'm sure there are more 'nicer' ways to do this, but this does everything i need.

**EDIT: I derped, by putting `default_server` in the listen directives, that of course breaks everything cause by default ssl would be broken... ooops. So im afraid i didn't think this thought and this isn't the solution after all :(**